# How can I write A map of byte Array into ZIP file

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to write a map of String and byteArray into a zip file without creating the physical file itself.
The String will be the name of the file. I managed to create the zip but the files inside the zip created has 0 byte

```
public void zipFiles2(Map<String, byte[]> inMap) {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Desktop\\testing1.zip");
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> pair : inMap.entrySet()) {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(pair.getKey());
                System.out.println("Zipping the file: " + pair.getKey());
                entry.setSize(pair.getValue().length);
                zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                byte[] tmp = new byte[4 * 1024];
                int size = 0;
                zos.write(tmp, 0, size);
                zos.flush();

            }
            zos.close();
            System.out.println("Done... Zipped the files...");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(pair.getKey());
entry.setSize(pair.getValue().length);
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
zos.write(pair.getValue());
zos.flush();
```

You were writing zero bytes (`int size = 0;`) out of an empty `byte[]` (`byte[] tmp = new byte[4 * 1024];`) rather than the bytes from the Map.